# Getting value error often while trying to implement a GAN

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, generative-adversarial-network

This is the code I have where I have tried to implement a basic GAN:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#Set the seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

#load the required image files, convert them to array
data_path = r"C:/Users/jayanth.kumar/Desktop/pou_new/"
#Import as tf.Dataset
data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data_path, label_mode = None, image_size = (28, 28))
a = np.stack(data)

#Build the generator model
generator = tf.keras.Sequential()
generator.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128450*3, input_dim=100))
generator.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
generator.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
generator.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((9, 28, 28, 3)))

#Build the discriminator model
discriminator = tf.keras.Sequential()
discriminator.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(9, 28, 28, 3)))
discriminator.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128))
discriminator.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
discriminator.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

#Build the combined model
gan = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
gan.add(generator)
gan.add(discriminator)

#Compile the model
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

#Train the model
gan.fit(a, epochs=100)
```

When I run the model, I have been getting these different value error(s). Like for example:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "reshape_14" (type Reshape).

total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [3596600], output_shape = [9, 28, 28, 3]

Call arguments received by layer "reshape_14" (type Reshape):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 3596600), dtype=float32)
```

I have tried reshaping the array, changing the input dimensions such that it matches the input shape but every time when I do that and run the model, the error occurs for other layers i.e. for example reshape_15, reshape 18.

Comment: The number of units in the Dense layer must match the size of the `reshape` output, that is `9*28*28*3`

Comment: I have changed that and I'm getting this error: ```ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_38" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 100), found shape=(None, 9, 28, 28, 3)```